# Merge redundant rows while updating another table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables tracks, genres and genres_to_tracks like this:

```
create table TRACKS_DATA(
    id int,
    trackname varchar(50),
    primary key(id)
);

create table GENRES_DATA(
    id int,
    genrename varchar(25),
    primary key(id)
);

create table GENRES_TO_TRACKS_DATA(
    id int,
    genreid int,
    trackid int,
    constraint fk_genreid foreign key(genreid) references GENRES_DATA(id)
        on update cascade
        on delete cascade,
    constraint fk_trackid foreign key(track_id) references TRACKS_DATA(id)
        on update cascade
        on delete cascade
);
```

In the GENRES_DATA table I have some redundant rows like this:

```
id, genrename
5, 'Hip-Hop'
7, 'Hip-Hop'
10, 'Rap'
18, 'Hip-Hop'
```

I want to update GENRES_DATA in a way that the redundant rows will be merged to one and all the other tables will be updated automatically like this:

```
id, genrename
5, 'Hip-Hop'
10, 'Rap'
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the minimum id for each `genre` and use that.  First fix `GENRES_DATA`:

```
update GENRES_TO_TRACKS_DATA gd join
       (select g.*, min(id) over (partition by genrename) as new_id
        from GENRES_DATA g
       ) g
       on g.id = gd.genreid  
    set genreid = new_id
    where genreid <> new_id;
```

Then you can remove the excess records:

```
delete g
    from GENRES_DATA g join
         (select genrename, min(id) as min_id
          from GENRES_DATA gg
          group by genrename
         ) gg
         on g.id = gg.min_id
     where gg.min_id is null;  -- i.e., it is not the min id
```

Comment: `where genreid <> new_id;` Is this for performance reasons? It seems redundant

Comment: @Strawberry . . . It is redundant in MySQL, in the sense that MySQL does that comparison anyway.  I still think being clear about the intent of the code is good . . . and I only want to update rows where the value changes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! And how can I explicitly say that for example genre ids 5 and 7 must be merged to 5?

Comment: @TheodosisSiomos . . . That would seem to be a different question.  You would just update `set genreid = 5 where genreid = 7`.

Comment: Yes, but genreid is a primary key so there will be a duplicate error.

Comment: @TheodosisSiomos . . . You do this in the junction table and delete the row in the other table.